# Does there exist an elegant way to implement a "while-then-do" loop?

Tags: c, coding-style

A standard do-while implements the following logic:

```
do_something();
while(loop_condition) {
    do_something();
}
```

Is there a common (i.e. existing in C or Java or some other frequently used language) construct to implement the following?

```
while(loop_condition) {
    do_something();
}
do_something();
```

Suppose for example that I need to read a file line by line and do something whenever I hit every line beginning with `\t` or on `EOF`. Is there a less error-prone way of doing this without offloading the loop contents to a function?

Comment: Normally there is a way of modifying the condition such that it runs one more time than before

Comment: What you have looks fine to me. If `do_something()` is trivial code, it can be in that function. Otherwise, make it a function and call it, just like you have.

Comment: I must be in as much need for stimulants as NPE. I'm trying hard to understand the relationship of your example use-case and your pseudo-code. Perhaps showing *code* that exhibits the problematic "error-prone" method you're trying to avoid would help, because right now I'm not digesting the actual problem (and will fully admit the fog-of-eggnog if I'm the only one).

Comment: Are you searching ffor something like the
try {/*something*/) catch(/*something*/) {}
finally {/*something*/}
for a while loop?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I think I understand what the OP is getting at. I often find myself writing these "do this inside the loop and also once right after the loop has ended" constructs. That said, I think a concrete example would help improve the clarity of the question.

Comment: @WhozCraig `do_something` need not be a pure function. It is possible that the fact that `loop_condition` is false will drastically change `do_something`'s behaviour.

Comment: @NPE sure. if the "something" were as the pseudo code suggests, then your original `do { do_something(); } while (condition);` makes sense (and I would have upticked it). if the task at-hand *in* the loop is *different* than the task *after* the loop, then the naming in the pseudo code is dreadful.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I assume it's the same. Unless my coffee hasn't fully kicked in yet, a `do`-`while` loop doesn't fully solve the problem, since it doesn't run an additional iteration of `do_something()` after the condition has turned `true`.

Comment: @NPE Likewise here. As I see it the do-while difference isn't the hit-count; its the initial *eval* of the condition. the second pseudo code falls in lock-step with do-while, but will *not* eval the condition *before* the first do_something. If that condition-eval somehow has a side-effect of altering what do_something does (and that isn't apparent in the question), then do-while isn't going to help, tis true.

Comment: Neither of these loops are do{ ... }while; loops.  They are both while{ ... } loops

Answer (score 4):

How about the following:

```
loop_again = true;
while (loop_again) {
  loop_again = loop_condition;
  do_something();
}
```

or, alternatively:

```
do {
  loop_again = loop_condition;
  do_something();
} while (loop_again);
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could write something like this:

```
bool should_keep_going = true;
while (should_keep_going) {
    should_keep_going = loop_condition;

    do_something();
}
```

I'm not sure how clear that is. It might work better with a realistic example, where we could potentially name `should_keep_going` in a more meaningful or intuitive way.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose for example that I need to read a file line by line and do something whenever I hit every line beginning with \t or on EOF. Is there a less error-prone way of doing this without offloading the loop contents to a function?

Well, lines might begin with non-tab character and then encounter EOF before the end of the line. I'm assuming that you meant "EOF after the last line".

This code executes what you seem to be describing:

```
while ( 1 )
{
    char *ptr = fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp);
    if ( !ptr || ptr[0] == '\t' )
        do_something();

    if ( !ptr )
        break;
}
```

You could convert the `!ptr` check into a loop condition if you want.